# Creating array of objects in bash

Tags: bash

Is it possible to create an array of objects in bash?

That's how I'm trying:

```
declare -a identifications=(
  {
    email    = '...',
    password = '...'
  }
)

declare -a years=(
  '2011'
  '2012'
  '2013'
  '2014'
  '2015'
  '2016'
)

for identification in "${identifications[@]}"
do
  for year in "${years[@]}"
  do
    my_program --type=CNPJ --format=XLS --identification=${identification.email} --password=${identication.password} --competence=${year} --output="$identification - $year"
  done
done
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, and I'm not finding how to achieve that, since I'm not finding bash objects.

Comment: `bash` has only one data type: string. Even arrays are simply another form of syntactic quoting, to allow lists of strings containing arbitrary values (i.e., whitespace). (Associative arrays, introduced in `bash` 4, are slightly better, but still no where near sufficient to allow the types of data structures you are looking for.)

Comment: `ksh93` and later support variables defined as you describe. Unfortunately, `ksh` seems to be  abandon-ware, as even the man-pages pointed to from kornshell.com are now dead links (and have been for a while). AND I wouldn't be able to point you to documentation on how to use your ksh for that feature. (Its probably out there somewhere). Good luck.

Answer (score 45):

You could do some trickery with [associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) (introduced in Bash 4.0) and namerefs (see manual for [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare) and the first paragraph of [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) – introduced in Bash 4.3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A identification0=(
    [email]='test@abc.com'
    [password]='admin123'
)
declare -A identification1=(
    [email]='test@xyz.org'
    [password]='passwd1!'
)

declare -n identification
for identification in ${!identification@}; do
    echo "Email: ${identification[email]}"
    echo "Password: ${identification[password]}"
done
```

This prints

```
Email: test@abc.com
Password: admin123
Email: test@xyz.org
Password: passwd1!
```

`declare -A` declares an associative array.

The trick is to assign all your "objects" (associative arrays) variable names starting with the same prefix, like `identification`. The `${!prefix@}` notation expands to all variable names starting with *`prefix`*:

```
$ var1=
$ var2=
$ var3=
$ echo "${!var@}"
var1 var2 var3
```

Then, to access the key-value pairs of the associative array, we declare the control variable for the for loop with the nameref attribute:

```
declare -n identification
```

so that the loop

```
for identification in ${!identification@}; do
```

makes `identification` behave as if it were the actual variable from the expansion of `${!identification@}`.

In all likelihood, it'll be easier to do something like the following, though:

```
emails=('test@abc.com' 'test@xyz.org')
passwords=('admin123' 'passwd1!')
for (( i = 0; i < ${#emails[@]}; ++i )); do
    echo "Email: ${emails[i]}"
    echo "Password: ${passwords[i]}"
done
```

I.e., just loop over two arrays containing your information.

Comment: declare -n identification throws an error in bash and i looked up the -n option  and can't find anything about it?

Comment: @transformerTroy Do you have Bash 4.3 or newer? That's when it was introduced.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to use json to create objects. For me it makes it really easy and flexible.

Here is a oversimplified example.

I create a json file: devices.json

```
{
          "backup" : [{
                "addr":"192.168.1.1",
                "username":"backuper",
                "dstfile":"firewallconfig",
                "ext":".cfg",
                "method":"ssh",
                "rotate":"no",
                "enabled":"yes"
            }, {
                "addr":"192.168.1.2",
                "username":"backuper",
                "dstfile":"routerconfig",
                "ext":".cfg",
                "method":"ssh",
                "rotate":"no",
                "enabled":"yes"
            }]
 }
```

Bash script: task.sh

```
 # read the devices.json file and store it in the variable jsonlist
    jsonlist=$(jq -r '.backup' "devices.json")
        # inside the loop, you cant use the fuction _jq() to get values from each object.
        for row in $(echo "${jsonlist}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
            _jq()
            {
             echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
            }
         
        echo "backing up: $(_jq '.addr')"
        echo "using method: $(_jq '.method')"
        done
```

The guy who posted the original post can be found by googling "using json with bash" or something.

Comment: Can you please post the link to the original post? I googled "using json with bash" and did not find it. In particular I am looking for any documentation on the function _jq() (with the underscore). Is _jq() actually a separate function from jq() or is that some bash syntax that I am not familiar with?

Comment: i think it was in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284745/how-to-manipulate-a-jq-output-using-bash

But hes not really explaining much.

_jq is just a function we create in the for loop. 

I find this for loop a little confusing to at first. But its quite good.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install jq` Those who are getting `jq: not found`

Comment: What distro and version of linux are you using?

Comment: d in Done is small. 
you will get Error : Unexpected End of File otherwise

Comment: Thank you Saurabh Mhase. I corrected it.